# Are there Zen monastries in India?

Tags: zen

I am searching for a Zen monastery in India.

My google search returns Vajrayana Tibetan monasteries.

Please let me know if you know a Zen monastery in India.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [World Buddhist Directory](http://www.buddhanet.info/) which may be helpful (I don't know any personally).

This URL -- http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/search.php?keyword=&search=Search&country_id=42&province_id=0&tradition%5B%5D=mahayana -- returns 35 "Mahayana" matches in India, and several of these are Zen (or probably Zen even if they don't say "Zen").

Comment: Thank you so much...didnt knew of this search website....thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

There is a temple associated with Sogenji and [Shodo Harada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shodo_Harada) of the [Rinzai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rinzai_school) sect in India: [Indozan Sogenji](http://onedropzen.org/community/india/indozan_sogenji).

Answer (score 0):

There is a Zen Ashram near Kodaikanal called - Bodhi Zendo Ashram. Goolge it, you will find the website and location along with contact detials.